# How to pass one extra hidden keypress in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass one extra hidden keypress to the textbox? Because this code takes one extra keypress to load the list in auto complete drop down list.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#zipcode").on("keyup", function(event) {
        if(this.value.length == 5){
            var zicpcode= $("#zipcode").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://pages.em.essilorusa.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707d2a7242227e94bba8efcc7ce6da09facd&zip="+zicpcode,
                type: "get", //send it through get method
                success: function(results) {
                    var res=results.substring((results.indexOf("<rs1>")+5),results.indexOf("</rs1>"));
                    var splitted = res.split("|");
                    var distinct = [];

                    $.each(splitted , function(i, el){
                        if($.inArray(el, distinct ) === -1) 
                            distinct.push(el);
                    });
                    $("#zipcode").autocomplete({ source: distinct }); 
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"one extra keypress"*? When you've entered five numbers, the function fires ?

Comment: @adeneo `.autocomplete()` not initialized until five characters already set as `input` value , additional key press required after `.autocomplete()` initialized for drop down menu to be displayed ?

Comment: Did you try just triggering it with `$("#zipcode").autocomplete("search");`

Comment: @adeneo: I am passing zip code which has max length 5, earlier there was less data when i did not given limitation, fetching the data easily but now it has 30K zip code it takes 2 min. to load the list in drop down. So that i am passing 5 character length then only its fire auto complete. it working fine (faster) but now its take one extra key press or backspace button to pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appaear to be loading `.autocomplete()` `source` after five characters already in `input type="text"` , `.autocomplete()` not initialized , dropdown not appear until sixth character input ?

Try

```
$("#zipcode").autocomplete({
  minLength:5,
  source:function(request, response) {
    var term = request.term;
        if ( term in cache ) {
          response( cache[ term ] );
          return;
        }

        $.getJSON( "http://pages.em.essilorusa.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707d2a7242227e94bba8efcc7ce6da09facd&zip=" + term, function( results, status, xhr ) {

          var res = results.substring((results.indexOf("<rs1>")+5),results.indexOf("</rs1>"));
                var splitted = res.split("|");
                var distinct = [];

                $.each(splitted , function(i, el){
                    if($.inArray(el, distinct ) === -1) 
                        distinct.push(el);
                });
          cache[ term ] = distinct;
          response( distinct );
        });
  }
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g5zn9fs9/

See [Autocomplete - Remote with caching](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache)

Comment: Thanks for guiding me on this.  I am trying work with this code but still it's not loading list to drop down.

Comment: @VikasTiwari See updated post , jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g5zn9fs9/ . Note, ""http://pages.em.essilorusa.com/page.aspx?QS=773ed3059447707d2a7242227e94bba8efcc7ce6da09facd&zip=" + term" not appear to return `json` ?

Comment: I got that. and made little change in my code also and it's working. I just initialize autocomplete before ajax.